# Howto cache completing-read inputs

Tags: completion, persistence

Is there a simple framework for making previous inputs of `completing-read` **persistent** *across emacs restarts*?
For instance if I start with: 
`(completing-read "test:" '("a" "b") nil nil)` and enter "c" the next time I start emacs and execute I want the collection to be `(completing-read "test:" '("a" "b" "c") nil nil)` instead. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no history for single minibuffer instances so I'm using this approach where `magit-gerrit-reviewers` is the `'("a" "b" "c")` list:

Saving history

```
(defun magit-gerrit-write-review (file)
   (with-temp-file file
       (insert "(setq magit-gerrit-reviewers '")
       (prin1 magit-gerrit-reviewers             (current-buffer))
       (insert ")" )))
```

Loading history:

```
(if (file-exists-p "~/.gerrit.reviewers")
             (load "~/.gerrit.reviewers"))
```

And using it:

```
(completing-read "Reviewer Name/Email:" magit-gerrit-reviewers nil nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes: just put `(savehist-mode 1)` in your `~/.emacs` and that should do the trick.

[ Tho not quite in the way you describe: `c` will still not be among the completion candidates.  But it will be in your *history* and hence accessible via `M-p`, `M-s`, ...  ]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can persist any global variable, by adding it to the value of option `savehist-additional-variables`.  This includes any minibuffer history variable.
2. Minibuffer history variables are used (typically) by `completing-read`.  You can use `M-p` and `M-r` to retrieve previously used minibuffer inputs when you are prompted by `completing-read`. See [(emacs) Minibuffer History](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html).
3. However, there are many different minibuffer history variables.  The most common, catch-all variable is `minibuffer-history`.  You can try persisting all of the minibuffer history variables you can find ;-), but be aware that any code can add a new such variable.
4. None of what I've said puts minibuffer history entries into the default set of **completion candidates** for any `completing-read` call. Input history and completion candidates are two different things.
5. If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then during minibuffer *completion* (including `completing-read`):

   - You can use [**`M-h`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_History_Enhancements#M-h) to match your current input against the minibuffer history directly.
   - Use [**`M-<pause>`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_History_Enhancements#M-pause) to restrict the current set of completion candidates to those you've used previously.  If you use `C-u M-pause`, then the previously used candidates are ordered chronologically, most recent first.
6. If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use [**`M-o`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_History_Enhancements%M-o) to complete against the history list during ***any*** minibuffer inputting, even without completion (i.e., whether the minibuffer is being used by `completing-read` or some other function).